# what is the difference between SETA and EQU in arm assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

Both instructions seem to set a value to a variable.
I don't see a clear difference between both of them.

The documentation for SETA is given here: 
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_asm/armclang_asm_dom1361290022931.htm

The documentation for EQU is given here:
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a51/a51_st_equ.htm

Comment: To quote from your first link: _EQU defines a constant, whereas GBLA and SETA define a variable._ Also, `EQU` allows for _" register-relative value or a PC-relative value"_ not just numbers and isn't limited to 32 bits.

Comment: Note neither of these are instructions...They are directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SETA assigns to an assemble time variable which can reassigned multiple times. EQU sets a constant, which can not be changed, has the same value whenever it is referred, can in some cases be used before it is assigned, and can be section relative.